# YouTube app cast function to Google mini speakers

Tags: google-home

I can cast YouTube app to a Smart TV.
On Android phones, can YouTube app cast to Google mini speakers as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Youtube app will only cast to devices with screens.

You can cast just the audio from Youtube using Chrome on the desktop

[image]